# Issue with running cmd file with administrator privileges from windows 10

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, administrator

I have problem with running a `cmd` (batch) file via *Right-click > Run as Administrator*.

I am trying to add addresses to a host file, but can't. (Access is denied.)

When I start a `cmd` instance as an administrator, then type `host.cmd` (the file i created), addresses are added to host file, but when I start `host.cmd` by Right-clicking and selecting *Run as administrator*, the access is denied.

I know in Windows 7 that worked, but don't know why can't work in Windows 10.
I have 200 machines on which I need to block specific addresses and it will take much more time if I have to add them by starting an instance of `cmd` then starting `host.cmd`.

Comment: Have you tried opening an adminitrator command prompt (run cmd.exe as admin) and then executing your .cmd or .bat file from there?

Comment: This depends on the security token and the rights of the underlying files. you may want to check this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/8988059/2934389

Comment: I tryed that and that worked, as i specified above, but i need it to work from right click > run as administrator

Comment: Seems to be working for me on Windows 10 (batch file > right click > run as administrator).

Comment: Salman A - Did you try to edit hosts file with batch file?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved issues. Apparently i have some permissions issues. Resolved it by installing Tweaking.com - Windows Repair tool that resets most of the windows settings and permissions to default.
And another issue, using cmd like this:

@echo off

SET NEWLINE=^& echo.

FIND /C /I "facebook.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%^216.119.147.103 facebook.com>>%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

FIND /C /I "www.facebook.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%^216.119.147.103 www.facebook.com>>%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

ipconfig /flushdns

But if i use hosts program that from https://code.google.com/archive/p/hostscmd/downloads    gets eror

Anyway, thanks for help, realy appreciate it